# Wix force component to be copied always

Tags: wix

I have a setup made with wix and I have several components that reference third party dlls. I run the setup and installed the application and now I'm doing an upgrade. The version of my third party is the same, but the content is different. I cannot change the AssemblyVersion. 
When I run the upgrade it will replace the old version of my application, but not the third party dlls. I assume this is because they are the same version. 
Can I force the setup to always overwrite an existing file?

Answer (score 1):

As a solution I used RemoveFile to remove the file and thus ensuring the file is always replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your upgrade so that it's sequenced afterInstallInitialize to see if that works, because that should uninstall the older product completely and then install the new one. There have been some issues with this where Windows sees that some file versions are already installed and predicts (incorrectly) that it won't need to replace them. If you see this, it's safe to change the Component Id to see if that fixes the problem because your upgrade is early. Sometimes it's necessary to manually sequence RemoveExistingProducts to before CostInitialize to fix this, but you may not need any of this if simply moving the upgrade to after InstallInitialize works.

Otherwise, your safest bet is to increment the file version because that's what's used by overwrites to disk, and you can use Visual Studio to change it.

If you're installing to the GAC, you could change the AssemblyVersion so they get installed, and also install a policy assembly to redirect calls for the older assemblyversion to the newer one. I'm assuming "can't change" is because of version-bound clients.

So there are some possibilities, but without knowing how your upgrade is scheduled or where the files are being installed I can't be specific.